# C# 'static abstract' method alternative to instantiate child class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstract

I am aware that what I'm asking isn't going to work this way, but I think my initial idea is not that stupid.

So, imagine a code structure like this:

```
abstract class Element
class A : Element
class B : Element
class C : Element
```

The Element parent class is handling file loading and saving of the child classes to a data structure like a XML file.

To save all Elements the Element class creates the basic XML structure and passes an XmlElement to each child class's 'OnSave()' method.
Each child has a slightly different data structure so they are implementing how to save themselves under the XmlElement the parent passed them.

To load however, the parent class should iterate through a given XML file and instantiate the child objects based on the information contained inside of the file.
Because the saving system is configured to store all child instances under a branch for the corresponding type it knows which type to instantiate for each data set.
Because the file structures of all child objects are again slightly different, it would be smart to have the childs implement a static function that creates a instance of itself filled with the data passed to said function by the parent.
Because I would require all childs to implement this function I instinctively started typing

```
protected static abstract Element Load(XmlElement xml);
```

Until I noticed that this doesn't make sense.

My question now is: How would a system like this be implemented in a smart way?

Edit:
Note that the Load function of Element would be static.

Comment: Why not use, for example, `protected abstract Element LoadChild(XmlElement xml);` abstract method and implement it in every child element?

Comment: @SeM because I would need an instance of the child type itself before creating a new instance of the child using 'LoadChild()'. I thought of this as well and it could work by creating a "loader instance" first, but I was looking for a more elegant way to solve this.

Comment: Any reason you don't use an existing library to serialize/deserialize to XML ?

Comment: @Spotted I looked at some but decided against them because doing it manually allows me more control over the XML Layout and it's also a good excercise to get comfortable with using File IO / XML in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Factory Method/Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

> In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created. This is done by creating objects by calling a factory method—either specified in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by calling a constructor.

The basic idea is to move your create(instantiate logic of you derived classes) to a separate class/method.

When you introduce a new derived class you only need to implement your new derived class and update your factory method.

Expanding on your example:

```
public abstract class Element
{
    public abstract void Load(XmlElement xml);
}

public sealed class ClassA
    : Element
{
    public override void Load(
        XmlElement xml)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class ClassB
    : Element
{

    public override void Load(
        XmlElement xml)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class ClassC
    : Element
{
    public override void Load(
        XmlElement xml)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public static class ElementFactory
{
    public static Element Create(
        XmlElement element)
    {            
        if (element.Value == "1")
        {
            return new ClassA();
        }
        else if (element.Value == "2")
        {
            return new ClassB();
        }
        else if (element.Value == "3")
        {
            return new ClassB();
        }

        throw new Exception("Could not determine element class");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
var xmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("element1");

var element = ElementFactory.Create(xmlElement);

element.Load(xmlElement);
```

You can also drop the load method and use the constructor of each derived class:

```
public abstract class Element
{
    public Element(
        XmlElement xml)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class ClassA
    : Element
{
    public ClassA(XmlElement xml) : base(xml)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class ClassB
    : Element
{
    public ClassB(XmlElement xml) : base(xml)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class ClassC
    : Element
{
    public ClassC(XmlElement xml) : base(xml)
    {
    }
}
```

Updated Factory:

Then your calling code becomes simpler:

```
public static Element Create(
    XmlElement element)
{            
    if (element.Value == "1")
    {
        return new ClassA(element);
    }
    else if (element.Value == "2")
    {
        return new ClassB(element);
    }
    else if (element.Value == "3")
    {
        return new ClassB(element);
    }

    throw new Exception("Could not determine element class");
}
```

Updated usage:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
var xmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("element1");

var element = ElementFactory.Create(xmlElement);
```

Comment: I like this approach, allthough I'm just realizing an easier way.
You pointed towards moving the loading logic into the constructor of the childs. This would make the loading with the factory easier, however if the XmlElement is passed as a parameter to the Constructor I might as well completelty ditch the factory and construct the object from the XmlElement if it's not null, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Uebertreiberman The factory is their to separate your create logic. How would you achieve it without the Factory?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I wouldn't seperate the logic. When using the Factory system I would need to update the factory class each time I change the construction inside the childs, because of that I think it's wiser to have the complete construction inside the child class to make maintenance easier.

Comment: okay. Glad I could point you into the right direction. Please remember to accept my answer if you feel it is worthy.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake, your answer is still the best solution. I can't have abstract constructors wich leaves me at the same point as earlier.
I'll implement the factory, thanks for the help.